# JDBC connection lifecycle for Connection Pool (Hikari) reuse

Tags: jdbc, hikaricp

Hikari: 2.4.7

PostgreSQL JDBC driver: 9.4-1201-jdbc41

I'm trying to understand what must be done to a `java.sql.Connection` object for it to be available again in the 
connection pool?

I've just introduced connection pooling to a multi threaded application that was 
previously standing up / tearing down connections with each SQL statement.

What I have noticed, after introducing Hikari, is that as soon as I hit `maximumPoolSize` every attempt
thereafter to `HikariDataSource.getConnection` will fail due to `connectionTimeout`. So it seems like I'm not "releasing" this connection somehow.

The typical use of the `Connection` object is:

```
# omits Exception handling, parameter substitution, result evaluation. 
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = hikariDataSource.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.executeQuery();
preparedStatement.close();
```

Is there anything else that is expected to be done on this connection to get it eligible for reuse in the connection pool?

`Autocommit` is on. `Connection.close()`, unless doing something special when provided by Hikari, seemed like the exact thing I wanted to avoid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know Hikari specifically, but for every connection you take out of a connection pool, you have to *return* that connection when you are done with it.

Typically this is done using `Connection.close()` - the pool hands out a wrapper function where `close()` doesn't physically close the connection, only returns it.

So your code should look like this:

```
Connection con = hikariDataSource.getConnection();
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.executeQuery();
preparedStatement.close();
con.close(); // this returns the connection to the pool
```

Of course the two `close()` methods should be called in a `finally` block.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Checked out the [source](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/dev/src/main/java/com/zaxxer/hikari/pool/ProxyConnection.java#L228) and looks like your assertion is spot on - I can see recycling behaviour happening in `Connection.close` and `PoolEntry.recycle()`. Will give it a crack and come back with upvotes and green ticks.

Comment: Or better: use try-with-resources